# Windows run app in closed environment and reverse all changes made after exit

Tags: windows

Is there any way (except some virtual machine) to run an app on Windows in totally reversable (closed?) environment? I mean to be able to fully undo all changes made in the process of installing and running? I found some threads about it, but don't find them useful. Restore point is not a solution. Too many things may go wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Look into [sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/).

Wikipedia: It allows you to create isolated operating environments in which applications can be run or installed without permanently modifying the local system.

Registry, memory, and disk environments are all destroyed after you close down the individual sandbox.

Comment: I will accept the answer after tests, but upvoted, thanx!